# Filament .......Select createOptionForm

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

In my modal, I have created two resources: PicklistOptionResource and PicklistResource. These resources are essential for storing and managing data. Once the data is passed
I need help logic for saving the data, I can ensure that the information remains available even after the initial passing.

```
   Section::make('Picklist Section')
                                ->hidden(function ($get) {
                                    $allowedType = [FieldTypeEnums::PICK_LIST];
                                    return !in_array($get('field_type'), $allowedType);
                                })
                                ->schema([


                                    Select::make('Picklist')
                                        ->label('Picklist')
                                        ->options(Picklist::pluck('name'))
                                        ->createOptionForm([
                                            TextInput::make('name')
                                                ->label(strval(__('cranberry-muffin::cranberry-muffin.form.input.picklists.name')))
                                                ->afterStateUpdated(function (Closure $set, $state) {
                                                    $set('slug', Str::slug($state));
                                                })
                                                ->reactive()
                                                ->required(),
                                            TextInput::make('slug')
                                                ->label(strval(__('cranberry-muffin::cranberry-muffin.form.input.picklists.slug')))
                                                ->required(),
                                            Textarea::make('description')
                                                ->label(strval(__('cranberry-muffin::cranberry-muffin.form.input.picklists.description')))
                                                ->columnSpan(2),
                                            Repeater::make('add_picklist_options')
                                                ->label(strval(__('cranberry-muffin::cranberry-muffin.repeater.picklist-options')))
                                                ->schema([
                                                    TextInput::make('name')
                                                        ->label(strval(__('cranberry-muffin::cranberry-muffin.form.input.picklist-options.name')))
                                                        ->afterStateUpdated(function (Closure $set, $state) {
                                                            $set('slug', Str::slug($state));
                                                        })
                                                        ->reactive()
                                                        ->required(),
                                                    TextInput::make('slug')
                                                        ->label(strval(__('cranberry-muffin::cranberry-muffin.form.input.picklist-options.slug')))
                                                        ->required(),
                                                ])->columnSpanFull()
                                                ->columns(2)
                                                ->createItemButtonLabel('Add New Picklist Option')
                                        ])->columns(2)
                                ])



                                ->hidden(function ($get) {
                                    $allowedType = [FieldTypeEnums::PICK_LIST];
                                    return !in_array($get('field_type'), $allowedType);
                                }),
```

Comment: In the Section Component, you have added 2 times `hidden()` and you have not mentioned the input `field_type` in your code.

Comment: and what you are looking for, please clear the concept here

Comment: https://discord.com/channels/883083792112300104/1126129722519195739/1126129722519195739

if u have discord plz refer this thread

Comment: I don't have this

Comment: now I am able to save data using 
->relation() method
using https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#creating-new-records

but now got another situation
if any picklist is selected from the dropdown 
I want to auto-fill the createOptionForm 
with respected data
when clicked +

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12yoJBonpv0JguuBW_QT8ARI8Nt81z0bo/view?usp=sharing
file link